# OnPhotonSerializeView Call only on specific condition

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I am new in Photon Multiplayer With Unity. I am stuck with a OnPhotonSerializeView() function. This function call every time in second[With Serialization Rate], But I want it to call when a specific bool value change. Like state change of player. Any one have idea about it please help me.
Thanks

```
    public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
        {
            if (stream.IsWriting)
            {
                    // Here I want to add condition
                    stream.SendNext(AppConfig.avatarObj.avtaarGender.ToString());
                    stream.SendNext(SerializeToXmlString(AppConfig.avatarObj.beard));
                    stream.SendNext(SerializeToXmlString(AppConfig.avatarObj.coat));
                    stream.SendNext(AppConfig.avatarObj.face);
                    stream.SendNext(AppConfig.avatarObj.hair);
                    stream.SendNext(SerializeToXmlString(AppConfig.avatarObj.hairColor));
                    stream.SendNext(AppConfig.avatarObj.isBeard);
                    stream.SendNext(AppConfig.avatarObj.isCoat);
                    stream.SendNext(AppConfig.avatarObj.isMoustache);
                    stream.SendNext(AppConfig.avatarObj.isSpecs);
                    stream.SendNext(SerializeToXmlString(AppConfig.avatarObj.moustache));
                    stream.SendNext(SerializeToXmlString(AppConfig.avatarObj.pant));
                    stream.SendNext(SerializeToXmlString(AppConfig.avatarObj.shirt));
                    stream.SendNext(SerializeToXmlString(AppConfig.avatarObj.shoes));
                    stream.SendNext(SerializeToXmlString(AppConfig.avatarObj.specs));
                    stream.SendNext(SerializeToXmlString(AppConfig.avatarObj.tie));
                    updateData = false;
                    print("Sending Data");
               
               
    
            }
            else if (stream.IsReading)
            {
                
                avtaarGenderStr = (string)stream.ReceiveNext();
                beardStr = (string)stream.ReceiveNext();
                coatStr = (string)stream.ReceiveNext();
                faceIndex = (int)stream.ReceiveNext();
                hairIndex = (int)stream.ReceiveNext();
                hairColorStr = (string)stream.ReceiveNext();
                beardValue = (bool)stream.ReceiveNext();
                coatValue = (bool)stream.ReceiveNext();
                moustacheValue = (bool)stream.ReceiveNext();
                specsValue = (bool)stream.ReceiveNext();
                moustacheStr = (string)stream.ReceiveNext();
                pantStr = (string)stream.ReceiveNext();
                shirtStr = (string)stream.ReceiveNext();
                shoesStr = (string)stream.ReceiveNext();
                specsStr = (string)stream.ReceiveNext();
                tieStr = (string)stream.ReceiveNext();
    
                if (info.photonView.ViewID == localPV.ViewID)
                {
                    SetData();
                }
                print("Reciving Data");
    
    
    
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: I think in such a use-case you should rather use [PackObjects (SyncVars)](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/simple/simplepackobjects) which handles this automatically and also only transmits the changed values and not everything all the time

Comment: Thanks @derHugo, But I just want to apply a bool condition in the syntax that is  if dress change DressChanged=true; and if DressChanged is true Write data like           
 if (stream.IsWriting){ DressChanged=false}

Comment: Well you can do that .. I wouldn't though ... then you have additional bool flags for each of your fields ... just clutters the component a lot .. also you will have to check yourself all the time if a certain field changed ... a `SyncVar` would handle all of this internally already all on its own